# In Word 2013, wildcard that matches beginning of the document

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

In Word 2013, using Search and Replace with or without wildcards enabled, I want to replace each occurrence of `Hello` at the beginning of a paragraph for `Bye`.

The search pattern:

> ^pHello

only works for non-first line and does not match `Hello` at the beginning of the very first paragraph of the document.

How can I match `Hello` at the beginning of the document? In Perl this would be done as `s/^Hello/Bye/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcard to match the beginning of the document seems not to exist.

What I did was to add a paragraph mark at the start of the document, do my searches, then remove the paragraph mark. Here is how it looks like in Perl:

```
my $word = Win32::OLE->new ('Word.Application', 'Quit') or die $!;

$word->Selection->HomeKey ({Unit => wdStory}); # to the beginning of the doc
$word->Selection->TypeText ({Text => "\n"}); # add the ^p
$word->Selection->HomeKey ({Unit => wdStory}); # to the beginning of the doc

my $search = $document->Content->Find; 

$search->{Text}              = "^pHello";
$search->Replacement->{Text} = "^pBye";
$search->Execute ();

$word->Selection->Delete; # delete the ^p
```